# Is $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ smaller than or equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the cardinality of all sequences with coefficients in an infinite set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/whats-the-cardinality-of-all-sequences-with-coefficients-in-an-infinite-set)

Is $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ smaller than or equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$?

I thought I saw this kind of statement somewhere, but I do not remember it.

Can anyone show me the proof of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Two days ago it was [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/109455/6460)

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/14434/742).

Answer (score 37):

They are actually equal, $2^{\aleph_0}\leq \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}\leq (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0} $

Answer (score 11):

Depending on your precise definition of "cardinal", the theorem below may require the Axiom of Choice (in fact, to make it really useful it does require it).

**Theorem.** For all cardinals $\lambda$ and $\kappa$, with $\kappa$ infinite, if $2\leq \lambda\leq\kappa^+$, then $\lambda^{\kappa}=2^{\kappa}$.

*Proof.* $2^{\kappa}\leq \lambda^{\kappa}\leq (\kappa^+)^{\kappa}\leq (2^{\kappa})^{\kappa} = 2^{\kappa\kappa} = 2^{\kappa}$. $\Box$

(AC is used to get $\kappa\kappa=\kappa$; the assertion that every infinite set $X$ is bijectable with $X\times X$ is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice).

**Corollary.** $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

*Proof.* Take $\lambda=\aleph_0$, which satisfies $2\leq \lambda \leq \aleph_0^+=\aleph_1$. $\Box$

Comment: Don't need choice for the special case of $\kappa = \aleph_0$, though....

Comment: @Hurkyl: Correct, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

We need to find an injection from $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ to $2^\mathbb N$. We need to encipher a sequence of natural numbers as a binary sequence. The first thought might be to concatenate the binary expansions of the elements from a sequence in $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$. This doesn't work because it's not not an injection: from the resulting binary sequence, we can't tell where one natural numbers ends and another starts. We can easily fix it by taking $3^\mathbb N$ instead of $2 ^\mathbb N$, which is fine because, as I'm sure you know, the sets are equinumerous. We obtain an additional, third, symbol to use in our cipher. We can now use it as a separator in our, previously binary, sequence.

Comment: Or you can just code $(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)$ by $a_0$ 1's followed by a 0 followed by $a_1$ 1's followed by a 0 etc.